# What's the measure of the angle $PFB$ in the figure below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:  The angle $B$ of an isosceles triangle $ABC (AB = BC)$ measures $48°$.
Points $P$ and $Q$ are marked on the $BM$ median. The prolongation of $AQ$ intersects $BC$ in $F$.
If $B, P, Q$ and $M$ form a harmonic range, calculate $\angle PFB$.(Answer $66^o$}

My progress:

I made the drawing and the relationship for the segment to be harmonic...but I don't know if there is missing data or there is another relationship with angles because I don't understand much about this subject. by Geogebra $FP$ is angle bisector triangle $BFM$ and $\angle FPB = 90^o$ ...Someone would know how to explain this issue

Condition for the four points $ACBD$ to form a harmonic range:
$\frac{BQ}{PQ} = \frac{BM}{MQ}$

BM ís median amd angle bissector therfore $\angle PBF = 24^o$

By solution $\angle PBF =24^0 \therefore FPB = 90^o$

but how did he come to the conclusion that $\angle FPB = 90^o$ ?

[image]

Comment: $FP$ need not bisect $\angle BFM$: In the degenerate case $P=Q=M$, $F=C$ it is clearly false, and you can approach this degenerate case obviously by choosing $Q$ arbitrarily close to $M$.

Comment: @user10354138  By Geogebra, in my figure $PF$ is angle bissector triangle BFM

Comment: Your image is a special case, user is right. But yes, $BM\perp PF$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, $\small FP$ need not bisect $\small \angle BFM$. Though the observation $\small BM\perp FP$ holds.

Let's prove the vice versa.

Draw perpendicular line $\small FD$ to $\small BM$.

[image: IMG]

We see that $\small \triangle BDF\sim\triangle BMC\implies\dfrac{BD}{BM}=\dfrac{DF}{MC}.$

Due to being isosceles, we know $\small MC=AM$.

Again $\small \triangle QDF\sim\triangle QMA\implies\dfrac{DF}{AM}=\dfrac{QD}{QM}.$

Thus combining above,
$\small \dfrac{BD}{BM}=\dfrac{QD}{QM}$ or $\small \dfrac{BD}{QD}=\dfrac{BM}{QM}.$

Therefore, $\small B$, $\small D$, $\small Q$, $\small M$ form a harmonic range.

Hence, eventually $\small P\equiv D$.

Comment: FP need not bisect, but as FP  it is perpendicular to BM  then $\angle PFB$ necessarily be $66^o$, correct?

Comment: Yes, @petaarantes. And from my image you can clearly see the first fact.(image to scale)

Comment: grateful for the clarifications and resolution